# Android Opengl es 1 - asynctask causing strange behaviour on some devices

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, android-asynctask

I am making a tower defense game in which I would like separate asyncTasks to handle all the unit movements, collision, damage, etc; and I want the GL Thread to only handle drawing...

So I have my 3 asynctasks in MyGLSurfaceView extends glSurfaceView class.

I handle onTouchEvents via an override in my GLSurfaceView.

Everything runs directly on the GL thread until it is time to run the mobs through the maze, at which I use a sequence of a Handler h posting a series of "prepare" methods loading the mobs for the level, and preparing various other required entities. The last step in this process is to edit the sharedpreferences which in turn triggers the 3 asyncTasks (through the implementation of onSharedPreferencesChangedListenner in MyGLSurfaceView (NOT my Renderer))

On my older devices (Nexus S and an older Samsung galaxy tab), this always works perfectly.
On my Galaxy S4, it only works about 80-90% of the time.
When it doesn't work, various alternate results can occur
:
- The app remains responsive, and keeps drawing everything that is required on screen, minus anything that was changed by the asynctasks; strangely, using Log, I noticed that the asynctasks also seem to be running properly, showing expected values in the log (monsters are moving properly, over the proper path, while towers are correctly firing missiles at them, and these missiles are behaving as expected (causing damage and potentially causing mob death on impact). Visually, I see a clump of mobs on the start waypoint, my towers, my game area, my UI (which remains totally clickable and interative with 0 lag). Just nothing is moving. I noticed, when this behavior is observed, that if I press the home key to trigger onPause, and then return to the app, triggering onResume, the action resumes normally, from the beginning (as if all the previous Log posts from my asynctasks were lost).
This is what usually happens when the app fails.
What could be causing this? Are my asyncTasks sometimes working on a separate instantiation of my renderer? Why does it always work on older devices but not always on the new device?

- The app crashes, due to a null pointer on my array of mobs (maybe things are executing out of order)?

Should I be avoiding asynctask when using openGL es?

Should I even be doing this? (updating mob locations via doInBackground and simply drawing the objects with their latest coordinates (as determined in the asynctask))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `AsyncTasks` for that. There are multiple problems that might arise:

- `AsyncTasks` are not guaranteed to be executed in the order they are started.
- The behaviour changed over time, so expect to experience weird things on different platform versions
- There is a limited number of `AsyncTasks` that are allowed to run at the same time. If you start more, they are queued and only started later. And more frustratingly, this number changed between api versions.

These paragraphs from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) might be of interest:

> **Order of execution**
>
> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.
>
> **public final AsyncTask executeOnExecutor**
>   ...
>
> Warning: Allowing multiple tasks to run in parallel from a thread pool is generally not what one wants, because the order of their operation is not defined. For example, if these tasks are used to modify any state in common (such as writing a file due to a button click), there are no guarantees on the order of the modifications. Without careful work it is possible in rare cases for the newer version of the data to be over-written by an older one, leading to obscure data loss and stability issues. Such changes are best executed in serial; to guarantee such work is serialized regardless of platform version you can use this function with SERIAL_EXECUTOR.